# I want to redirect the index.php from a Wordpress site to another URL, and all the other URLs in the WP site separatley

Tags: redirect

So, here is the problem:

I need to have a redirect from website.ro/ to website.com/

Website.ro is on wordpress.

At the same time, all the sub-links like website.ro/title will be redirected individually to website.com/different_title_same_content

If i do this:
Redirect 301 /index.php http://website.com/
Redirect 301 /title http://website.com/different_title_same_content

What happens is that website.ro is on wordpress, that means that all the sublinks are called through index.php (i think, but not sure) and if i do a redirect on index.php than all the other links will be redirected to the homepage and not to their corresponding innerpage.

Its like setting a master rule when i'm redirecting the index.php.

What i would like to do is redirect index.php to a homepage, and any other variation on its corresponding subpage on the new website.

Can it be done?

EDIT: I have added a little of the code that i have to write:

Redirect 301 /Zuzu newsite/portfolio/cases/doc/47860743/

Redirect 301 /Antena1 newsite/portfolio/cases/doc/47860862/
...and so on for allmost 100 urls. (i had to post here without http and www since i am not allowed here more than 2 urls)

The reason i have to do this is that in the past, many of the links on the oldsite appeared in articles, press, blogs and so on, and i do not want to loose traffic that the old links generated on each page.

At the same time, i want to redirect the homepage to the newsite homepage, but if i do this with:

Redirect 301 / newsite/

it will redirect all the other links to the main page of the newsite and not to its corresponding article.

Its the same if i do Redirect 301 /index.php newsite/

since the old website is on wordpress and i think that all the pages are called through index.php(and some variables)

Also, the urls on the newsite.com are not rewritable as to rename them as the old ones so i can create an automated redirect generally valid.

WHAT IS THERE TO DO?

Answer (score 1):

Look into this it may solve your issue

http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/

Best of luck!

Comment: No. It doesn't actually, but thanks for trying. What i wanted to say is that the newdomain links cannot be rewritten since they load content from other parties and display them.